# Easily change vallidation group in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, validation

I recently needed to use a custom validation in Spring Boot.  I quickly ran into the problem that my custom validation ran before the already in place validation.  I was able to overcome that difficulty by creating a custom group for my custom validation. ([this helped out a lot](https://javapointers.com/spring/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-validation-order-example/))

My question boils down to why cannot I not change the group in the custom validation interface.

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = EndShiftValidation.class)
public @interface CustomValidation {
    String message() default "custom error message;
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};  //why can't I change the default group here?
    //seems like I should be able to change above to:
    //Class<?>[] groups() default OtherGroup.class;
    public abstract Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

From my point of view I should be able to change the group in the above code.  Instead, I had to change it where I annotate with @Validated

```
 @PostMapping
public ModelAndView getFormData(@Validated(ValidationSequence.class) ...){
```